# Move guitar bridge towards low E string

Tags: guitar

It seems to me that the high E string has less space (not just because it is thinner) than the low E string. When playing the high E string I often slip and end up at the side of the fret instead on top.

Is there a simple way to adjust this? I know I can adjust the action with a screwdriver but I haven't found anything concerning my problem.

UPDATE: Here is the picture of the guitar. (below is the picture of another guitar I own)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to clarify a couple things for the best answers. First you should post pics of your actual guitar and preferably close up shots of both the neck at whatever point you're having a problem and at the bridge. You should also be more clear about what the problem is. I'm not exactly sure what "slip and end up at the side of the fret instead on top" means. Do mean the string is slipping off the neck? Or what do you mean by "top of the fret"?. And "less space" in what way? Side to side? Or height/action?

Answer (score 2):

While generally strings and necks are arranged symmetrically, with respect to how much space each string has, your top E could be given a little less space as it actually doesn't need as much space as your low E.

If your fret ends are worn (perhaps from pushing the strings over the ends) then it will feel like there is less room.

From your photo it does look like there is actually a slight issue as it looks similar to my Warlock. Mine has it to cram the extra string in, but your guitar doesn't have that excuse :-)

It's likely to be either with the bridge position, or the neck itself. As moving the bridge can be tricky I'd suggest a visit to a luthier is worthwhile.

That said, I'm of the opinion that this you can get around this with good technique, as @Todd mentioned in his comment. With more practice, you can get used to an incredibly small neck - I have a 7 string Warlock with very little room at the edge of the neck, but I only ever slip off it when I want to (sometimes it makes for an interesting sound...) - so just practice. Be more precise in how your fingertip presses the string, how hard you press, and how perpendicular your movement is to the surface of the fretboard.

[image]

Comment: While technique is certainly part of it, the photos do show that the top string is just about directly above the place on the fret where it starts being rounded off, so I would say that's too little space.  Probably the neck is a bit out of alignment.